# NoSuchElementException occurs when Iterating through Java ArrayList concurrently

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method similar to the one below:

```
public void addSubjectsToCategory() {
    final List<Subject> subjectsList = new ArrayList<>(getSubjectList());
    for (final Iterator<Subject> subjectIterator =
            subjectsList.iterator(); subjectIterator.hasNext();) {
         addToCategory(subjectIterator.next().getId());
    } 
}
```

When this runs concurrently for the same user (another instance), sometimes it throws `NoSuchElementException`. As per my understanding, sometimes `subjectIterator.next()` get executed when there are no elements in the list. This occurs when being accessed only. Will method synchronization solve this issue?

The stack trace is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at org.cmos.student.subject.category.CategoryManager.addSubjectsToCategory(CategoryManager.java:221)
```

This stack trace fails at the `addToCategory(subjectIterator.next().getId());` line.

Comment: I suggest apply synchronize only to the concurrently executing code block rather than synchronizing the entire method.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, Does that mean, synchronizing to be added on to  addToCategory(subjectIterator.next().getId()); code block which leads to the exception?

Comment: How about adding the above list to Collections.synchronizedList() and then do the iteration?

Comment: Yes, synchronized list is a better approach.

Comment: I think problem could be with copy of the list at the beginning. For statement is fine; if list is empty, it will never be inside, because hasNext() is executed before each loop, even before the first one.

Comment: With the exception of the external call to `getSubjectList` there is nothing in this code that needs to be synchronized or should fail due to concurrency: you are iterating via a local var which you create once per executing thread. Your problem most likely lies with `getSubjectList()` or with iterating over the result of that call if that result is not a newly constructed collection but an iterable.

Comment: Randomly adding synchonized keywords is not the solution. You need to understand where and why it fails first. Please provide the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen. I added the stack trace in the above.

Comment: `ArrayList` isn't threadsafe, you cannot iterate it concurrently. Simple.

Comment: If the issue reproduces when you concurrently work on **different** instances, synchronizing won't help. Can you share the code for `addSubjectsToCategory`?

Comment: @Mureinik . Yes im also wondering about that. It is just adding the Subjects to an another list. However, stack trace does not show anything inside of addToCategory();  It says the issue is with subjectIterator.next().getId();

Comment: Are you concurrently using the SAME iterator or are they different iterators?

Comment: @VictorNoël, I did not get you.

Comment: If you have 2 iterator (retrieved from `iterator()` from two different `ArrayList` moreover), it's not possible that concurrent use of those iterators impact each other. Something is missing in your description to understand the problem: where is the concurrence happening?

Comment: @BoristheSpider There's the concept of a **Lock**, you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).
If you want to know how to make **non thread-safe** operations into **thread-safe** operations, then you will find [Semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) from the *java.util.concurrent* API, to be extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks @P.Soutzikevich. I had no idea. I mean you could just use a non-blocking threadsafe collection; but your idea seems awesome.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No problem buddy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic rule of iterators is that underlying collection must not be modified while the iterator is being used.

If you have a single thread, there seems to be nothing wrong with this code as long as `getSubjectsList()` does not return null OR `addToCategory()` or `getId()` have some strange side-effects that would modify the `subjectsList`. Note, however, that you could rewrite the for-loop somewhat nicer (`for(Subject subject: subjectsList) ...`).

Judging by your code, my best guess is that you have another thread which is modifying `subjectsList` somewhere else. If this is the case, using a SynchronizedList will probably not solve your problem. As far as I know, synchronization only applies to List methods such as `add()`, `remove()` etc., and does not lock a collection during iteration.

In this case, adding `synchronized` to the method will not help either, because the other thread is doing its nasty stuff elsewhere. If these assumptions are true, your easiest and safest way is to make a separate synchronization object (i.e. `Object lock = new Object()`) and then put `synchronized (lock) { ... }` around this for loop as well as any other place in your program that modifies the collection. This will prevent the other thread from doing any modifications while this thread is iterating, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Jurez for your time. subjectsList does not get modified by other threads. It just holds the info of subjects. Does it matter since a new list is created for iteration instead of iterating through  subjectsList directly?

Comment: @Kevin Then, what does "concurrent mode" mean exactly?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. The system being a swing clients and separate JVMs are created for each instances, it might not a concurrency problem due to instances. But this issue occurred while doing the same task in two separate application instances. That is why i referred this as a concurrency problem. However, this was occurred couple of times and now can not be reproduced. I'm kind a lost.

Comment: Also could you please kindly let me know the different between locking using a separate object and using the subjectsList object. This is for my knowledge.

Comment: If "concurrent" means two different JVM processes, then this is not really concurrency in strict sense because JVMs are completely isolated from each other.

Comment: However, there is a different possibility - I've looked at `ArrayList.Itr.next()` and the only way it can produce `NoSuchElementException` is when it thinks its size is actually different from the underlying array. This could imply a problem during the copying (`new ArrayList<>(getSubjectList())`) if the original list is modified while it is being copied.

Comment: As for the synchronization on separate object: it is exactly the same as using `synchronized` method - except you have more control over it. Synchronized method is the same as putting `synchronized(this)` around entire method body.

Comment: Yes. That is a very good finding. But this happens if i remove any element from the  original subjects list while coping is being done ?.

Comment: Actually, I need to know is there any different between locking using a separate object like Object lock = new Object(); and using my own subjectsList object in the above code. synchronized(lock) and synchronized(subjectsList)

Comment: Yes. Copying is done in two steps - one is copying the array and second is copying the size. The larger the array, the longer the time and the higher the probability. If you suspect this is the scenario, you actually need to synchronize on original list in the same way as proposed above - a single lock that covers copying (first line of your method) and other modifications to original list elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks Jurez. Will try it out and come back

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like another thread is calling the method and grabbing the last element while another thread is about to get the next. So when the other thread finishes and comes back to the paused thread there is nothing left. I suggest using an ArrayBlockingQueue instead of a list. This will block threads when one is already iterating.

```
public void addSubjectsToCategory() {
    final ArrayBlockingQueue<Subject> subjectsList = new ArrayBlockingQueue(getSubjectList());
    for (final Iterator<Subject> subjectIterator =
         subjectsList.iterator(); subjectIterator.hasNext();) {
        addToCategory(subjectIterator.next().getId());
    }
}
```

There is a bit of a wrinkle that you may have to sort out. The ArrayBlockingQueue will block if it is empty or full and wait for a thread to either insert something or take something out, respectively, before it will unblock and allow other threads to access.

Comment: Thanks @Jim , Yes that is what exactly happens. Will try this out and come back..

Comment: I'm not sure if this would explain the problem. If another thread enters `addSubjectsToCategory`, it will create its own copy of list - that should not interfere with the original thread's iterator.

Answer (score 3):

```
subjectIterator.hasNext();) {
```

--- Imagine a thread switch occurs here, at this point, between the call to `hasNext()` and `next()` methods.

```
addToCategory(subjectIterator.next().getId());
```

What could happen is the following, assuming you are at the last element in the list:

- thread A calls hasNext(), the result is true;
- thread switch occurs to thread B;
- thread B calls `hasNext()`, the result is also true;
- thread B calls `next()` and gets the next element from the list; now the list is empty because it was the last one;
- thread switch occurs back to thread A;
- thread A is already inside the body of the for loop, because this is where it was interrupted, it already called `hasNext` earlier, which
  was true;
- so thread A calls `next()`, which fails now with an exception, because there are no more elements in the list.

So what you have to do in such situations, is to make the operations `hasNext` and `next` behave in an atomic way, without thread switches occurring in between.
A simple synchronization on the list solves, indeed, the problem:

```
public void addSubjectsToCategory() {
    final ArrayBlockingQueue<Subject> subjectsList = new ArrayBlockingQueue(getSubjectList());
    synchronized (subjectsList) {
        for (final Iterator<Subject> subjectIterator =
            subjectsList.iterator(); subjectIterator.hasNext();) {
                addToCategory(subjectIterator.next().getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that there may be performance implications with this approach. No other thread will be able to read or write from/to the same list until the iteration is over (but this is what you want). To solve this, you may want to move the synchronization inside the loop, just around hasNext and next. Or you may want to use more sophisticated synchronization mechanisms, such as read-write locks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Collections.synchronizedList(list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) if all you need is a simple invocation Sycnchronization. But do note that the iterator that you use must be inside the Synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

As I get you are adding elements to a list which might be under reading process. 
Imagine the list is empty and your other thread is reading it. These kinds of problems might lead into your problem. You could never be sure that an element is written to your list which you are trying to read , in this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised not to see an answer involving the use of a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or Guava's `ImmutableList` so I thought that I would add such an answer here.

Firstly, if your use case is such that you only have a few additions relative to many reads, consider using the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) to solve the concurrent list traversal problem. Method synchronization could solve your issue, but `CopyOnWriteArrayList` will likely have better performance if the number of concurrent accesses "vastly" exceeds the number of writes, as per that class's Javadoc.

Secondly, if your use case is such that you can add everything to your list upfront in a single-threaded manner and only then do you need iterate across it concurrently, then consider Guava's [`ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) class. You accomplish this by first using a standard `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList` or a [builder for your `ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.Builder.html). Once your single-threaded data entry is complete, then you instantiate your `ImmutableList` using either [`ImmutableList.copyOf()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf-java.util.Collection-) or [`ImmutableList.build()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.Builder.html#build--). If your use case will allow for this write/read pattern, this will probably be your most performant option.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @entpnerd

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a suggestion that would probably solve your problem, considering that this is a concurrency issue.

If making the method *addSubjectsToCategory()* synchronized solves your problem, then you have located where your concurrency issue is. It is important to locate where the problem occurs, otherwise the information you provided is useless to us, we can't help you.

IF using synchronized in your method solves your problem, then consider this answer as educational or as a more elegant solution. Otherwise, share the code where you implement your threading environment, so we can have a look.

```
public synchronized void addSubjectsToCategory(List subjectsList){
  Iterator iterator = subjectsList.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
    addToCategory(iterator.next().getId());
}
```

or

```
//This semaphore should be used by all threads. Be careful not to create a
//different semaphore each time.
public static Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

public void addSubjectsToCategory(List subjectsList){
  Iterator<Subject> iterator = subjectsList.iterator();
  mutex.acquire();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
    addToCategory(iterator.next().getId());
  mutex.release();
}
```

Synchronized is clean, tidy and elegant. You have a really small method and creating locks, imho is unnecessary.
**Synchronized** means that only 1 thread will be able to enter the method at a time. Which means, you should use it only if you want 1 thread active each time.

If you actually need **parallel** execution, then your problem is not thread-related, but has something to do with the rest of your code, which we can not see.

Comment: This won't solve any problem as the concurrent access isn't from this method but from somewhere else. As other answers point out, adding random concurrency constructs in one place without understanding the problem is like to solve exactly nothing.

Comment: Based on what the OP has said, his threads access this method.
I provided an answer, based on the information that the OP provided. I don't understand what your point is. What do you mean the concurrent access isn't from this method? If the program accesses this method in such way, that it creates a race condition, then a method needs to become thread-safe. Adding random comments in one place without understanding the concept, will help for exactly nothing

Comment: Thank you gentlemen